# libclang: get interface cursor from implementation cursor

Tags: objective-c, cursor, implementation, superclass, libclang

world!  I am trying to use libclang to determine the superclass that an Objective-C method belongs to.  I have a cursor representing an instance method (CXCursor_ObjCInstanceMethodDecl).  When I get the cursor's parent, I get a cursor of kind CXCursor_ObjCImplementationDecl.  I need to be able to get the interface cursor from this last cursor in order to determine the method's superclass.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`clang_getCanonicalCursor()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__XREF.html#gac802826668be9fd40a017523cc7d24fe) on the cursor for the `@implementation` declaration will return the cursor for the `@interface` declaration. Visiting the children of this cursor will provide access to its superclass reference.

You can also use [`clang_getOverriddenCursors()`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html#gac308b03420c550e00c61153dc63deac8) on the cursor for the method to determine if it is overriding another from a superclass, protocol, or category.